# Determine if a statistical difference exists in the # of passes of two test methods?

Tags: statistics

The company I work for wants to see more "passing results" so they ran two methods of tests with their sample pool.

In method 1, whichever sample a consumer eats first is considered a "pass".

In method 2, the quantity of food consumed determines if one or both products pass.

Each individual test is a test of store brand vs. national brand.
Each individual test was performed separately using both methods.
If it's important, the consumers were different for the method 1 and method 2 execution.

Ignoring the fact that there are better ways to conduct the test in the first place, how can I tell whether the method with more passing products had a significant impact?  Which type of test should I be using?

Comment: I guess you'd first want to have a look at [two-sampe t-tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests)

Comment: IIUC, given the same number of consumers for both methods, method 2 by design can produce more "passes" than method 1?

Comment: @stefan Yes, and that is the case.  I've been asked to see if it's a "statistically significant" difference but I'm not sure how to proceed with handling the data.

Comment: OK. Can you provide a bit more detail about how your individual measurements look like, e.g., do you have #passes {0, 1 or 2} per consumer for each method? How many measurements do you have for each method? Giving us an example of the data would be helpful.